# C++ How to call an if statement loop?

Tags: c++

C++ code where a user enters 2 integers, then the program outputs how many numbers were multiples of 3 between those integers, including both numbers, and how many numbers were divisible by 5.

Here is my code.  I think I am not calling the if statements correctly.  Maybe I need a switch?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numb1, numb2;
    int sentinel;
    int counter = 0;
    int mult3 = 0;
    int mult5 = 0;
    cout << "Enter an integer:";
    cin >> numb1;
    cout << "Enter another integer:";
    cin >> numb2;
    cout << endl;

    sentinel = (abs(numb2-numb1)+1);

    if(numb1 % 3 == 0 && counter <= sentinel) {
        mult3++;
        numb1++; 
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        numb1++; 
        counter++;
    }

    cout << endl;
    counter = 0;

    if(numb1 % 5 == 0 && counter <= sentinel) {
        mult5++;
        numb1++; 
    }
    else {
        numb1++;
        counter++;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << mult3 << " " << "numbers are divisible by 3 in between your entered integers." << endl;
    cout << mult5 << " " << "numbers are divisible by 5 in between your entered integers.";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is your issue?

Comment: What is it currently doing and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: this belongs to codereview

Comment: You seem to want to write an algorithm that does some of the steps more than once.  `if` and `switch` are not really helpful for that.  Instead you'll want `while` or `for`.

Comment: I suggest searching the internet for "C++ fizz buzz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short version for your code is given below. Checkout the while loop(not ran, just from top of my head).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numb1, numb2;
    int sentinel;
    int counter = 0;
    int mult3 = 0;
    int mult5 = 0;
    cout << "Enter an integer:";
    cin >> numb1;
    cout << "Enter another integer:";
    cin >> numb2;
    cout << endl;

    while(numb1 <= numb2){
        mult3 += (numb1%3)==0?1:0; // (numb1%3)?0:1
        mult5 += (numb1%5)==0?1:0;
        ++counter;
        ++numb1;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << mult3 << " " << "numbers are divisible by 3 in between your entered integers." << endl;
    cout << mult5 << " " << "numbers are divisible by 5 in between your entered integers.";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not looping it at all, so this will only execute once.

```
while(counter < sentinel)
{
  //run your tests and increment the appropriate variables if the numbers are divisible by 3 or 5
  counter++;
}
```

start by evaluating `the lowest of the 2 entered numbers + counter % 3 == 0`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wanted a loop.  I used the suggestion of the while loop.  I have a while loop for numb1 <= numb 2 and a second while loop for numb2<= numb 1, but at the end of the first loop, all numb1 = numb2, so they possibly get an extra count if numb2 is divisible by 3 or 5.  I need to make any series that goes through the first while loop to automatically skip the second while loop.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I had to use 3 separate while loops.  One for <, one for >, and one for =.  When I just had a <= and >=, the first loop would feed into the second.  I took out the sentinel and the counter thanks to Avezan's help.  Thanks everyone.